# What's the point of salting water if you mash or blend anyway?

Tags: soup, salt, boiling

It makes sense if you cook pasta, for example: you want those noodles salty inside too. If you mash or blend, however, there's no such thing as inside or outside. As a result, I never salt water when I boil potatoes for mashing. If you salt afterwards, some of the salt won't go down the drain. One Gordon Ramsay, on the other hand, an experienced chef, made a point of salting boiling water when cooking his broccoli soup. He didn't explain his reasoning, let alone provide some peer-reviewed publications that would corroborate whatever point he had, but it made me thinking: could there, indeed, be good reasons for salting water if you mash or blend your vegetables?

No! It's not just about "adding salt to potato water". I respectfully urge you to reopen the question

Comment: You expect chefs to show scientific papers for all their cooking techniques?

Comment: `you want those noodles salty inside too.` No, *you* do, evidently. *I* don't.

Comment: Salting potatoes after boiling gives a *totally* different flavour [one I personally find unpleasant]. I can **smell** the difference between potatoes boiling in salted & unsalted water. For most other veg, salting after cooking needs more salt than during & still doesn't taste quite the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wonder whether it was tested in a double-blind randomized trial. I could easily be

Comment: By the way, it's not a duplicate of those questions, you got it wrong

Comment: It doesn't need a double-blind test. I can tell if [someone] forgot the salt in potatoes by the smell that works its way into the living room. My girlfriend was at one time convinced I could actually smell salt. I can't - no-one can - but I can smell the difference if the potatoes are cooking without salt. [& it's no good arguing in comments if you don't agree with the duplicate reason, you need to edit your question to make the distinction clear, then it will go into the review queue for potential re-opening.]

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev with the other questions (plus the comments here) we have established that "salt the water" and "salt afterwards" produces a different taste. What is your question about, if it isn't about "adding salt to the water"?

Comment: @rumtscho those "similar questions" are about potatoes. Mine is more general